# How to fix issue uuid_generate_v1() does not exist in postgresql , actually i have the function under public schema

Tags: postgresql, uuid

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from da.test_get(cast(? as integer),cast(? as text),cast(? as text),cast(? as text),cast(? as text))]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: spiexceptions.UndefinedFunction: function uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: Traceback (most recent call last):

[image]

Comment: And what is `da.test_get`?

Comment: da.test_get is a user function i write for our system, it will invoke the function  uuid_generate_v1()

Comment: And what is the source code of `da.test_get`?

Comment: insert into tmp.xxx_list
    select  x.id,
            x.circuit_id,
            uuid_generate_v1(),
            uuid_generate_v1()
        from circuit_ma x
            left join tmp.xxx_list  y
                on x.id = y.panel_id
                and x.circuit_id = y.circuit_id
        where y.panel_id is null;

Comment: I did not write the schema name of uuid_generate_v1(), because it is under schema public, and schema public is in the search_path .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) statement used a wrong search path. (This is not shown by `\df`.)

You can either tell the function to use the value in the environment, or set it explicitly to a correct value:

```
ALTER FUNCTION da.test_get RESET search_path;
```

```
ALTER FUNCTION da.test_get SET search_path = da, public;
```

Comment: Great idea, i will have a try. Actually this error in the system can not be replay every time. It happens by chance.